# AngularJS int mapping is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Guys I have a Model as followed which returned from Ajax call.

```
public partial class GroupForm
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual int? FormId { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Frequency { get; set; }     
}
```

In angular Ajax call I got a list of GroupForm and then using ng-repeat to show the FormID and Frequency, but instead showing the Frequency int value, I want to show string, so I do the mapping ,but It only show GroupId, the Frequency is not showing.
MY controller part as followed:

```
FrequencyMap = {
        1: "Annual",
        2: "Monthly",
        3: "Half Year"
    }

    $scope.mapFrequency = function (col) {
        return FrequencyMap[col];
    };
```

And my front  angualrJS code as folloed:

```
<ul>
                <li ng-repeat="w in GroupForm">
                    {{ w.FormId+ ', '+mapFrequency(w.Frequency)}}
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I am using this code, the ajax call return three GroupForm records, it's only showing 3 GroupId, but the frequency string is missing. However, If I use w.Frequency, it can show the int vale.
Please advice

How I get GroupForm as followed:

```
 $scope.GetAllGroupForms = function (Id) {
        var url = '/GroupForm/Details/' +Id;
        $scope.loading = true;
        DataSvc.getAjaxData(url)
         .then(function (data) {
             //success        
             $scope.GroupForm = data.data;
             $scope.loading = false;
         }, function (httpStatus) {
             //failed
             $scope.hasErrors = true;
             if (httpStatus === 404) {
                 $scope.errorMessage = "Couldn't retrieve Users Info";
             } else {
                 $scope.errorMessage = 'The system could not process your request, please try again or contact the system administrator.';
             }
             $log.warn(httpStatus);
             $scope.loading = false;
         });
    };
```

Comment: missing a closing parens after `mapFrequency(w.Frequency`

Comment: is your ng-repeat actually working? do you get 3 list items in your view...

Comment: I added the missing closing parens, but still not working

Comment: Binding a function as you do `{{ w.FormId+ ', '+mapFrequency(w.Frequency)}}` is a terrible practice. Why don't you save `FrequencyMap` the the scope (`$scope.map = FrequencyMap;`) and then just reference it from the view `{{ w.FormId + ', ' + map[w.Frequency] }}`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But this is not working. Thanks

Comment: @SteveTianqinGuo Please add to the question example of how `$scope.GroupForm` looks like, also show how you get the values from the server

Comment: @AlonEitan  Just updated. Please check

Comment: @SteveTianqinGuoThank you, try adding `<pre>{{ w | json }}</pre>` after `{{ w.FormId+ ', '+mapFrequency(w.Frequency)}}` - Do you see that the elements in the loop have a `Frequency` property? Does they match to the properties of `mapFrequency`?

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you so much for your help .I tried. Yes, it has frequency property, check as followed:  {
  "Id": 2,
  "GroupId": 1,
  "FormId": 2,
  "SortOrder": null,
  "Frequency": 2,
  "IsCollapsed": false,
  "IsDeleted": false
}    {
  "Id": 3,
  "GroupId": 1,
  "FormId": 3,
  "SortOrder": null,
  "Frequency": 1,
  "IsCollapsed": false,
  "IsDeleted": false
}

Comment: @SteveTianqinGuo unfortunately I have to go, but I'll come back for this tomorrow and try to help (But I hope someone else will do it before) Good luck

Comment: @AlonEitan  No problem. Thank you for you willing to help.

Comment: @SteveTianqinGuo And I'll just leave here a demo https://jsfiddle.net/vy3o039e/ with a simplified data like yours, as you can see - it works, so try comparing it to your code and it might help you understand what you're doing wrong in your code

Comment: @AlonEitan  Hey, I am really appreciate. Thanks a lot. I checked it and compared with mine, no difrrerence. Things wired, when I cleaned my solution and rebuilt, It worked.    Thank you for your approach. Can you post your approach in the answer, so that I can marked to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract the logic into your scope. If this doesnt work for you then something is either wrong with your data, or the way you're setting GroupForm

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('demoController', controller);
  
function controller($scope) {

  var frequencyMap = {
    1: "Annual",
    2: "Monthly",
    3: "Half Year"
  };
  
  $scope.GroupForm = [
    {
      FormId: 123,
      Frequency: 3
    },
    {
      FormId: 456,
      Frequency: 1
    },
    {
      FormId: 789,
      Frequency: 2
    }
  ];


  function getFrequency (frequencyId) {
    return frequencyMap[frequencyId];
  }

  $scope.formatGroupFormItem = function(groupForm) {
    var frequency = getFrequency(groupForm.Frequency);

    var result = groupForm.FormId;
    if(frequency) {
      result += ', ' + frequency;
    }

    return  result;
  };
}
```

```html
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script></head>
<body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demoController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="form in GroupForm">
        {{ formatGroupFormItem(form) }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I use this but nothing showing, even the formId is gone. It only showing three dot, which means I guess three records

Comment: No, Cuz I can get all the three GroupForm with Id and FormId before. Thanks

Comment: Im asking if you have any errors in your console when you tried this and it didnt work...

Comment: Thank you for helping. But it's still not working. I could not figure out why. Please check my update for GroupForm object, something due to this ?